# Bind ListView selected item to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

I have a ListView that holds a list of names, each name comes from a binding to an object containing a "name" field, like this:

```
public class User {
    public User() {}
    public User(string name, int ID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    public string name {set; get;}
    public int ID {set; get;}
 }
```

and the listView:

```
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvName" DisplayMemberPath="name"/>
```

and in the code behind I set lvName.ItemSource to an ObservableCollection of User objects, in the collection I have Users that can have the same Name, but not the same ID.

I also have a dataGrid, with 2 columns defined(one for name and one for ID), I want to make it so that when the user selects a row from the listview(which shows names of Users), the datagrid would be populated with all the User objects(both the name and ID) that have the same name as was selected in the listview.

how can I do that?

Note: I managed to bind the name field to a textblock, by doing this:

```
 Text="{Binding SelectedItem.name, ElementName=lvName}"
```

but I have no idea how to do it on a datagrid, let alone with the ID field as well as the name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be easily done using MVVM approach.
Assuming, that `User` class looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

you can define this view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
            new User { Id = 2, Name = "Mary" },
            new User { Id = 3, Name = "Peter" },
            new User { Id = 4, Name = "John" },
            new User { Id = 5, Name = "John" },
            new User { Id = 5, Name = "Peter" }
        };

        UsersView = new ListCollectionView(Users)
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var user = (User)obj;

                return SelectedUser != null && user.Name == SelectedUser.Name && user.Id != selectedUser.Id;
            }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; private set;  }
    public ICollectionView UsersView { get; set; }

    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get { return selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedUser != value)
            {
                selectedUser = value;
                UsersView.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
    private User selectedUser;
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UsersView}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: that's awesome, unfortunately I don't use the MVVM pattern in this project, is there a way of doing that without it?

Comment: @Stacker: actually, view model here is just a container for 3 properties: source collection, its filtered view and selected item. You can store all this stuff in code behind, and use `ListView.SelectionChanged` event instead of binding.