# Show properties of selected items in ListView in DataGrid in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

Screenshot:

[image]

Selecting items from above ListView shows their properties in the datagrid below.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="EmployeeSystem.Run_with_XML"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmployeeSystem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Run with XML" Height="398.299" Width="305.91" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Height="325" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListView Height="100" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding employees}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"/>
            <DataGrid Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesView}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Create New" Height="24" Margin="112,0,111,-30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**VeiwModel:**

```
class ViewModel
{
    private Employee selectedEmployee;
    public ICollectionView EmployeesView { get; set; }

    EmployeeManagerXML emx = new EmployeeManagerXML();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        EmployeesView = new ListCollectionView(emx.getEmployeesList()) //this is an ObservableCollection
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var Employee = (Employee)obj;

                return SelectedEmployee != null && Employee.Name == SelectedEmployee.Name;
            }
        };
    }

    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return selectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedEmployee != value)
            {
                selectedEmployee = value;
                EmployeesView.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been desperately trying to achieve this for days now...i searched google for hours...tried all the related pages on stackoverflow...This post is my last hope...someone please just show me where am going wrong with this. I already know this is a duplicate..[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300488/bind-listview-selected-item-to-a-datagrid) scenario is exactly the same as mine and I did everything exactly the same as that answer says...still mine doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any binding error you get in the output window?

Comment: there is no error in output window

Comment: Your ListView's ItemSource binds to "employees" property where is that property in your ViewModel?

Comment: employees is an ObservableCollection...it is in EmployeeManagerXML class...

Answer (score 1):

You should impliment `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to reflect changes in View

for example below,

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

  EmployeeManagerXML emx = new EmployeeManagerXML();

  public ViewModel()
  {

  }
  private Void RefreshEmployeeList()
  {
      EmployeesView = new ListCollectionView(emx.getEmployeesList()) //this is an ObservableCollection
    {
        Filter = obj =>
        {
            var Employee = (Employee)obj;

            return SelectedEmployee != null && Employee.Name == SelectedEmployee.Name;
        }
    };
  }
  private Employee selectedEmployee;
  private ICollectionView _EmployeesView;
  public ICollectionView EmployeesView 
  {
       get { return _EmployeesView; }
       set
       {
           _EmployeesView = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
  public Employee SelectedEmployee
  {
    get { return selectedEmployee; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedEmployee != value)
        {
            selectedEmployee = value;                
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            RefreshEmployeeList();
        }
    }
}
```

**MSDN**

> The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

Comment: but isnt that what ObservableCollection<> is for...
`[SerializableAttribute]
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, 
 INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: You can use `ObservableCollection` in the place of `ICollectionView ` check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)